# Setting Custom Coders & Handling Parameterized types

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have two questions related to coder issues I am facing with my Dataflow pipeline.

- How do I go about setting a coder for my custom data types? The class consists of just three items - two doubles and another parameterized property. I tried annotating the type with SerializableCoder but I still end up with the error "com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: Cannot provide coder based on value with class interface java.util.Set: No CoderFactory has been registered for the class." The Set actually contains the parameterized custom data-type - so I am assuming that the custom datatype is the problem. I could not find enough documentation/examples on the right way to do this. Please point me to the right place if its available.
- Even without the custom datatype, whenever I try switching to a parameterized version of Transform functions, it results in coder errors. Specifically, inside a complex transform which is parameterized, a ParDo works with parameterized types but when I apply a Combine.PerKey on the resulting PCollection after the ParDo, it results in the CoderNotFoundException.

Any help regarding these two items would be helpful as I am kind of stuck on this for sometime now.

Comment: The exact errors I get are:
-------------com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: Cannot provide coder based on value with class interface java.util.Set: No CoderFactory has been registered for the class.
------------- com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: Cannot provide coder for parameterized type com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.values.KV<java.lang.String, java.util.Set<customType<type>>>

Comment: Can you include a minimal code sample showing how you are setting the coder? Does your class implement the Serializable interface? Can you also include a sample of your parameterized transform?

Comment: This is how I setup my custom type. Right now, I am using a String type of the class and I am facing the problem.
  `@DefaultCoder(SerializableCoder.class)
  public class CustomType<T> implements Serializable { 
  }`

Comment: This is the transformer I am using - ideally, I want this transformer also to be parameterized so that I can pass the same type onto the CustomType but since it was causing problems, I moved to Stringized version but I am still facing the same set of CoderExceptions. If I remove both the CustomTypes and the type-parameterization in all the pipeline interactions, things work fine. So, I believe the problem is with using them only.

Comment: `static class Processor extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<KV<String, Set<CustomType<String>>>>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

    @Override
    public PCollection<KV<String, Set<CustomType<String>>>> apply(PCollection<String> items) {
        PCollection<KV<String, Set<CustomType<String>>>> partitionedItems =
                items.apply(ParDo.of(new ParDoFn()));

        PCollection<KV<String, Set<CustomType<String>>>> combinedItems = partitionedItems.apply(
                Combine.<String, Set<CustomType<String>>>perKey(new Merger()));`

Answer (score 14):

It looks like you have been bitten by two issues. Thanks for bringing them to our attention! Fortunately, there are easy workarounds for both while we improve things.

The first issue is that the default coder registry does not have an entry for mapping `Set.class` to `SetCoder`. We have filed [GitHub issue #56](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/56) to track its resolution. In the meantime, you can use the following code to perform the needed registration:

```java
pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoder(Set.class, SetCoder.class);
```

The second issue is that parameterized types currently require advanced treatment in the coder registry, so the `@DefaultCoder` will not be honored.  We have filed [Github issue #57](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/57) to track this. The best way to ensure that `SerializableCoder` is used everywhere for `CustomType` is to register a [`CoderFactory`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/CoderFactory) for your type that will return a `SerializableCoder`. Supposing your type is something like this:

```java
public class CustomType<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
  T field;
}
```

Then the following code registers a [`CoderFactory`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/CoderFactory) that produces appropriate `SerializableCoder` instances:

```java
pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoder(CustomType.class, new CoderFactory() {
  @Override
  public Coder<?> create(List<? extends Coder<?>>) {
    // No matter what the T is, return SerializableCoder
    return SerializableCoder.of(CustomType.class);
  }

  @Override
  public List<Object> getInstanceComponents(Object value) {
    // Return the T inside your CustomType<T> to enable coder inference for Create
    return Collections.singletonList(((CustomType<Object>) value).field);
  }
});
```

Now, whenever you use `CustomType` in your pipeline, the coder registry will produce a `SerializableCoder`.

Note that `SerializableCoder` is not *deterministic* (the bytes of encoded objects are not necessarily equal for objects that are `equals()`) so values encoded using this coder cannot be used as keys in a `GroupByKey` operation.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Those work-arounds have fixed the issue. I had fixed the SetCoder issue separately by force setting the Coder but since the Set contained my custom-types, I thought there was something wrong there as well.

Comment: A follow-up question - I have a Transform class which uses this custom-type. I tried making it generic like so `TransformFn<T extends Serializable> ...` within which I will work with PCollections containing CustomType<T> in some form. Now, I am getting **Cannot provide a Coder for type variable T because the actual type is unknown due to erasure.** for T. (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/CoderRegistry.java#L597) seems to throw out this error for any generic type. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you post a small code snippet in a new SO question? This way we can have more information and give full-length answer that focuses on this new problem.

Comment: I posted a new question [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591914/making-transformations-in-dataflow-generic)